# TikZ figure arrow problems

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot the below figure using TikZ but couldn't achieve the arrows properly.

I could essentially have the arrows from `B` nodes to `A` but not of the same type from `A` to `B`.

Is there a way to achieve this in TikZ?

**Logic is**:

*While going from node `A` to node `B`. The connecting arrows (wires) connect next `B`, where next means, not just below them but next to the below ones. Below each `A` there are two `B` but the wires connect to next nearest `B`*. The left going arrows has label *l* (i.e. left)

*While going from node `B` to node `A`. The connecting arrows (wires) connect just below `A`.*

[image]

This is my MWE(thanks to old collaborators):

```
\documentclass[border=0.1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  \colorlet{Mycolor1}{green!10!orange!70!}

\tikzset{
    mynode/.style = {circle, draw, thick, fill=black, inner sep=0pt},
    type1/.style = {mynode,black},
    type2/.style = {mynode,Mycolor1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\path[clip] (-3.1,-7.25) rectangle +(4.8,4.8);
\begin{scope}[rotate=45]
    \foreach \x in {-8,...,0}
      \foreach \y in {-9,...,0} {
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\type}{int(mod(abs(\x+\y),2)+1)};
         \draw[blue, -] (\x-0.6, \y) -- (\x+0.6, \y);
         \ifthenelse{\type=1}{\node[black,below] at (\x-0.22, \y+0.27) {$\scaleto{l_{1}}{4.5pt}$};}{}
         \ifthenelse{\type=2}{\node[black,below] at (\x-0.22, \y+0.27)  {$\scaleto{l_{2}}{4.5pt}$};}{}

         \draw[red,  -] (\x, \y-0.6) -- (\x, \y+0.6);
         \ifthenelse{\type=1}{\node[type\type] at (\x,\y) {\color{white}$A$};}{}
         \ifthenelse{\type=2}{\node[type\type] at (\x,\y) {\color{black}$B$};}{}
     }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This give us (I have the same wiring connection from step `B` to `A` but not from `A` to `B`):
[image]

EDIT: After working around, I could get my second step i.e. from step `B` to `A`. But lost my first step connecting below neighbors i.e. from step `A` to `B` (which is present in above case). Also, the left going arrows has label l (i.e. left)

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\path[clip] (-3.1,-7.25) rectangle +(4.8,4.8);
\begin{scope}[rotate=45]
    \foreach \x in {-8,...,0}
      \foreach \y in {-9,...,0} {
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\type}{int(mod(abs(\x+\y),2)+1)};
         \draw[blue, <-] (\x-0.8, \y+1) -- (\x+0.9, \y);
         \ifthenelse{\type=1}{\node[black,below] at (\x-0.22, \y+0.27) {$\scaleto{l_{1}}{4.5pt}$};}{}
         \ifthenelse{\type=2}{\node[black,below] at (\x-0.22, \y+0.27)  {$\scaleto{l_{2}}{4.5pt}$};}{}

         \draw[red,  <-] (\x+1, \y-0.8) -- (\x, \y+0.9);
         \ifthenelse{\type=1}{\node[type\type] at (\x,\y) {\color{white}$A$};}{}
         \ifthenelse{\type=2}{\node[type\type] at (\x,\y) {\color{black}$B$};}{}
     }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the logic in creating this graph and arrows?

Comment: @AndréC I edited my answer and gave the logic! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't explained your code which contains esoteric formulas like this: `\pgfmathsetmacro{\type}{int(mod(abs(\x+\y),2)+1)};` Your code is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly and given the hand-drawn diagram, is this what you are trying to do?[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  \colorlet{Mycolor1}{green!10!orange!70!}

\tikzset{
    mynode/.style = {circle, draw, thick, fill=black, inner sep=0pt},
    type1/.style = {mynode,black},
    type2/.style = {mynode,Mycolor1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\path[clip] (-3.1,-7.25) rectangle +(4.8,4.8);
\begin{scope}[rotate=45]
    \foreach \x in {-8,...,0}
      \foreach \y in {-9,...,0} {
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\type}{int(mod(abs(\x+\y),2)+1)};
         \draw[blue, <-] (\x-0.6, \y) -- (\x+0.6, \y);
         \ifthenelse{\type=1}{\node[black,below] at (\x-0.22, \y+0.27) {$\scaleto{l_{1}}{4.5pt}$};}{}
         \ifthenelse{\type=2}{\node[black,below] at (\x-0.22, \y+0.27)  {$\scaleto{l_{2}}{4.5pt}$};}{}

         \draw[red,  <-] (\x, \y-0.6) -- (\x, \y+0.6);
         \ifthenelse{\type=1}{\node[type\type] at (\x,\y) {\color{white}$A$};}{}
         \ifthenelse{\type=2}{\node[type\type] at (\x,\y) {\color{black}$B$};}{}
     }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not this. I already have this result with me. If I just put the direction, then I get it (which I didn't put, for the sake of quickness). Is there a way to change the step from `B` to `A`? As I have edited my answer. Thanks for the input!